# Interface should be changed before time-consuming task starts in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to implement the following behaviour of collectionView cell: by tapping on the cell the appearance of the cell should be changed first! And AFTER that, a time-consuming process should start:

```
@objc private func addItemsToBasket(_ button: UIButton) {
         button.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
         Basket.addItems(keys: planner.currentDayKeys())
}
```

but unfortunately, the cell changes appearance only after the time-consuming block is finished. If I comment "Basket.addItems(keys: planner.currentDayKeys())" the cell changes its appearance prompt.

I have already tried different options in GCD, nothing helped. But actually, if I don't define a Queue the code should run line by line. Right?

It should be a very common case.
Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: “ I have already tried different options in GCD” could you elaborate on what these were?

Comment: You shouldn't perform the time consuming task on the main queue. Dispatch it asynchronously onto a utility or user initiated queue.

Comment: *"... the code should run line by line. Right?"* -- Yes, that is exactly right, and that's why it's not working the way you want it to work. The result of `button.setTitleColor(...)` won't be visible until the next UI update. If your `planner.currentDayKeys()` is preventing the UI update, you won't see the button title change until your function stops blocking the UI. Show some of the *"different options in GCD"* that you've tried, and somebody can help you understand what you need to do. (and show what your `planner.currentDayKeys()` is doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, you should not perform time consuming tasks on the main queue. GCD will definitely help you in this case. Have you tried something like this:

```
@objc private func addItemsToBasket(_ button: UIButton) {
    button.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
    DispatchQueue.global.async {
        Basket.addItems(keys: self.planner.currentDayKeys())
    }
}
```

But you need to make sure that if you do some UI changes in your `Basket.addItems`, you need to dispatch them back to main by wrapping them inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure.

Comment: That's a good solution, the other I found is to delay time-consuming task using  `.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)` in that case UI has time to update itself, and after that time-consuming task starts.